# Как получить данные колонки индексов Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Считываю данные:

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv',';', index_col=['month'], parse_dates=['month'], dayfirst=True)
```

Смотрю на них:

```
print data.shape
print data.columns
data.head()
```

Вывод:

```
(168, 1)
Index([u'milk'], dtype='object')


   month    milk
1962-01-01  589
1962-02-01  561
1962-03-01  640
1962-04-01  656
1962-05-01  727
```

В какой-то момент мне необходимо построить график количества во времени. Каким образом получить данные колонки индексов (`month`)? Напомню, что мы ее указали индексом и в данных у нас только одна колонка с количеством. Конечно, можно отобразить как `data.plot()`, но мне хотелось бы сделать это вызвав `plot` у `matplotlib`.

Дополнительно вопрос о лучших практиках: в каких случаях обоснованно / следует использовать данные в качестве индекса?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Судя по выводу `data.head()`, вы либо не указали параметр `index_col=['month']` либо он отработал не так как ожидалось и столбец `month` оказался обычным столбцом, вместо того чтобы стать индексом.

Чтобы получить значения индекса DataFrame'а, достаточно воспользоваться атрибутом `DataFrame.index`.

Пример:

```
In [129]: df = pd.DataFrame({'val':np.random.rand(100)}, index=np.arange(100, 200))

In [130]: df
Out[130]:
          val
100  0.924396
101  0.960312
102  0.728403
103  0.435330
104  0.599777
..        ...
195  0.055345
196  0.560087
197  0.049506
198  0.819265
199  0.231141

[100 rows x 1 columns]

In [131]: plt.plot(df.index, df['val'])
Out[131]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x1a8815cfe80>]
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**UPDATE:** если на оси `X` - дата/время, то проще воспользоваться Pandas для визуализации:

```
In [154]: df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\download\data.csv', sep=';', parse_dates=True, index_col=0)

In [155]: df
Out[155]:
            milk
month
1962-01-01   589
1962-02-01   561
1962-03-01   640
1962-04-01   656
1962-05-01   727

In [156]: df.plot(y='milk')
Out[156]: <matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot at 0x1a889fabc88>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Значения индекса DataFrame:

```
In [157]: df.index
Out[157]: DatetimeIndex(['1962-01-01', '1962-02-01', '1962-03-01', '1962-04-01', '1962-05-01'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='month', freq=None)
```